# How to deploy MEAN application if i have separate folders for front-end and back-end?

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, mean-stack

I have developed a MEAN stack application with my RESTapi, i have separated my code into front-end and back-end 2 folders . How should i deploy/host my application on Heroku(or any platform and create a public domain )

pls check the image i have attached showing my project structure

Thanks community !!

[image: Image shows my Folder structure of my project]

Comment: There are infinite ways to deploy your application. The easiest one: Backend on heroku and frontend on Netlify. But do you want to deploy everything on one machine? That's completely possible but you have to build your frontend application first and let the backend serve it. It's also possible to configure a Docker container with two services talking to each other, or two containers and one docker-compose file. Whatever you choose, please stay away of Kubernetes ;)

Comment: A simple way, would be to use AWS. Build your angular file, import the dist folder to s3, use elastic beanstalk for your node backend, using the elastic beanstalk URL for your API calls on the front end. There are many tuts on hosting websites on S3 and AWS has a lot of info on hosting node on elastic beanstalk. You can also skip beanstalk and use ec2 with a Ubuntu instance install node/mongo on the instance.